# Chudnovsky algorithm python incorrect decimals

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, math, pi

my goal is to get 100.000 or 200.000 correct decimals of Pi in Python. For this, I have tried using the Chudnovsky algorithm, but I've got some issues along the way.

First, the program only gives me 29 chars, instead of the 50 I want to test the correctness. I know this is a small issue, but I don't understand what I've done wrong.

Second, only the first 14 decimals are correct. After those, I start getting inaccurate Pi decimals according to about all Pi numbers on the internet. How do I get way more correct decimals?

And last, how do I let my code run on all 4 of the threads I have? I've tried using Pool, but it doesn't seem to work. (Checked it with Windows task manager)

This is my code:

```
from math import *
from decimal import Decimal, localcontext
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
k = 0
s = 0
c = Decimal(426880*sqrt(10005))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()

    pi = 0

    with localcontext() as ctx:
        ctx.prec = 50

        with Pool(None) as pool:
            for k in range(0,500):
                m = Decimal((factorial(6 * k)) / (factorial(3 * k) * Decimal((factorial(k) ** 3))))
                l = Decimal((545140134 * k) + 13591409)
                x = Decimal((-262537412640768000) ** k)
                subPi = Decimal(((m*l)/x))
                s = s + subPi


    print(c*(s**-1))

    print(time.time() - start)
```

Comment: Note that `sqrt(10005)` is computing a square root using the built-in Python `float`, which is almost certainly using IEEE 754 binary64 format, and so it's limited to 53 bits of precision. You likely want `Decimal(10005).sqrt()` instead (after setting the decimal context appropriately).

Comment: Also, you do the final computation _outside_ the extended precision context. That computation will only give a result at the default context precision of 28 significant figures. For the multithreading question, I'd suggest making that a separate question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Immeadiately going to change the root and last print location.

Comment: The precision issue is fixed now, but the inaccuracy of the decimals moved from 15 to 28, so after 28 decimals I still get incorrect decimals.

Comment: @P3TER_ I've also tried to correct some inaccuracies in the code but I'm also finding errors from the 28th digit. I'm going to post the code below even if it does not solve the problem completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the small details discussed in the comments and proposed by @mark-dickinson I think I've fixed the multithreading but I haven't had a chance to test it, let me know if it works properly

**UPDATE:** Problems after the 28th digits were due to the assignment of sq and c before the `decimal` `context` change. Reassign their value after changing the `context` precision solved the problem

```
from math import *
import decimal
from decimal import Decimal, localcontext
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
k = 0
s = 0
sq = Decimal(10005).sqrt() #useless here
c = Decimal(426880*sq) #useless here

def calculate():
    global s, k
    for k in range(0,500):
        m = Decimal((factorial(6 * k)) / (factorial(3 * k) * Decimal((factorial(k) ** 3))))
        l = Decimal((545140134 * k) + 13591409)
        x = Decimal((-262537412640768000) ** k)
        subPi = Decimal((m*l)/x)
        s = s + subPi
        
    print(c*(s**-1))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()

    pi = 0

    decimal.getcontext().prec = 100 #change the precision to increse the result digits

    sq = Decimal(10005).sqrt()
    c = Decimal(426880*sq)

    pool = Pool()
    result = pool.apply_async(calculate)
    result.get()

    print(time.time() - start)
```

Comment: I've tested it, but my cpu usage hasn't gone up while running the code with enough calculations (5000) (so it isn't done before watching cpu usage).

Comment: @P3TER_ I don't know how to help you yet for multithreading but the problem of accuracy is solved

Comment: It looks good, but the max char length is 29 again.

Comment: @P3TER_ My output `3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706` is correct. Have you checked all the differences between your code and "my" code?

Comment: I've just copied the code above, yet my ouput is: ```3.141592653589793238462643386```

Comment: @P3TER_ Really don't know what to say, I'm sorry. To me the output is of 100 digits..

Comment: I ran it in repl.it and it indeed gave 100 decimals, so it's a problem on my IDE I think.

Comment: Yeah, in repl it works, so my problem is solved. And I will ask the multiprocessing question in another post if I'm going to run the final code offline, but for now, thanks a lot!